# How to use Analytics service to indicate a page view

Tags: java, codenameone

I'm trying to set up a page view when a certain form is shown, and this is a GUI builder project. I initialized the AnalyticsService with the Google Analytics ID and my app name in the initVars method, and then when I want to fire a page view I used the AnalyticsService.visit(page name, referer). When I view the Google analytics data, is always shows no page info.

What needs to be done to get page view information sent to Google Analytics? Am I calling the visit method incorrectly?

Here's the initialization:

```
public StateMachine(String resFile) {
        super(resFile);
        // do not modify, write code in initVars and initialize class members
        // there,
        // the constructor might be invoked too late due to race conditions that
        // might occur
    }

    /**
     * this method should be used to initialize variables instead of the
     * constructor/class scope to avoid race conditions
     */
    protected void initVars(Resources res) {
        Display.getInstance().lockOrientation(true);
        AnalyticsService.init("(my Analytics ID)",
                "rpcontrol.fastlaneinnovations.com");
        AnalyticsService.setAppsMode(true);
        AnalyticsService.setFailSilently(false):
....bunch more stuff}
```

And then elsewhere I try to trigger a page view:

```
@Override
protected void beforeDataLogs(Form f) {
    logsContainer = findLogsContainer(f);
    updateLogList();
    AnalyticsService.visit("Logs", "");
}
```

Comment: As this is a code-centric forum, can you please post the relevant code to assist with troubleshooting?

Comment: OK, I updated the questing with the code.

Comment: You don't need to invoke visit() in GUI builder apps as its implicitly called for you. You can open the network monitor tool in the simulator and see the calls that are made to the analytics service going to the servers and the servers responses.

Comment: Ok, I'll look at that. How can I set a page name though? In my analytics dashboard, it only says "No Page Title" for all the visits.

Comment: I've added an answer that I might have missed in the original question, the page value should generally work but might be failing due to the apps mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `AnalyticsService` class has two modes and if you created a mobile apps analytics you need to enable the apps mode using
[setAppsMode](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/analytics/AnalyticsService.html#setAppsMode-boolean-).

This is probably better than the default behavior of using the old mobile website approach, unfortunately I don't think we can flip the default as this would break existing applications that might rely on this API.

Comment: OK, I have appsMode set to true, I think the problem is likely that I don't understand the new apps mode for Google Analytics and what it should show on their mobile dashboard as I'm used to seeing website analytics.. I'll research that. Thank you.